# Building an NSString based on a variadic number of arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, variadic-functions, stringwithformat

My function takes a dictionary argument and a variadic number of `NSString` variables. All this combined is put in an `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` method, and is returned as a `NSURLRequest`. The method looks like this:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)buildPath:(NSString *)stringPath attributes:(NSString *)attribute, ...
{
    va_list list;
    NSString *eachObject;
    NSMutableArray *args = [NSMutableArray array];

    [args addObject:attribute];
    va_start(list, attribute);
    while ((eachObject = va_arg(list, NSString *))) {
        [args addObject:eachObject];
    }
    va_end(list);

    NSString *listOfAttributes = [args componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
    NSString *pathURL = _requestString[stringPath];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:pathURL, listOfAttributes];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    return request;
}
```

This is what it looks like when I call the method:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [_venueService buildPath:@"categories"
                                          attributes:_venueService.clientID, _venueService.clientSecret, _venueService.todaysDate, nil];
```

When I run the program, it crashes. When I log out `listOfAttributes` it gives me:

```
client_id, client_secret, 20140507
```

This is my 3 arguments, which is correct, and the `stringPath` (when I actually call it in my program I write `stringPath[@"categories"]`) which, when I NSLog gives me:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=%@
```

So, my question is, why would these two strings, combined in an `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` cause problems?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you casting the `NSDictionary` `stringPath` to an `NSString`? That makes no sense.

Comment: @rmaddy Because my NSDictionary contains NSStrings. If I didn't do it Xcode gave me warning about it. What should I do instead, if anything?

Comment: Casting is just putting off a runtime crash. The 1st argument to `stringWithFormat:` must be an `NSString`, not an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Does it make a difference that when I call the function, I pass in e.g stringPath[@"categories"] which contains a string?

Comment: You need to pass a string that contains whatever format specifiers you need. We have no idea what's in your dictionary so you shouldn't be asking us what should be passed in. Only you know what those strings are.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the tips. Going to fix that. Do have any input on my problem though? I realize I have to few arguments in my [stringWithFormat:] method, but I also tried -[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:], still no luck..

Comment: @Nilzone- you call with a buildPath of @"categories" - this is just an NSString with no format specifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Justin pointed out, there is a much simpler way of doing this. NSString has a -initWithFormat:arguments: method that does exactly what you want.

Also, your method name has a few issues:

1. Naming convention - you should indicate in the method name its purpose (creating a URL request)
2. You are passing in an (NSDictionary *) for the path, but casting it to an (NSString *) when you use it. The two objects are not type compatible. I'm supposing this might be a typo when you copy-pasted your code?
3. Might as well use the same calling convention as NSString's +stringWithFormat: method.

Given all of the above, the method becomes something like (without error checking):

```
- (NSURLRequest  *)URLRequestWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ... {
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, format);
    NSString *urlPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:arguments];
    va_end(arguments);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    return request;
}
```

This worked fine with a call like:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [self URLRequestWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories/client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=%@", @"One",@"Two",@"Three"];
NSLog(@"Request: %@", request);
```

With output:

```
2014-05-07 09:52:30.645 Test[5888:60b] Request: <NSURLRequest: 0x8c64f30> { URL: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories/client_id=One&client_secret=Two&v=Three }
```

Comment: When I copied your code and run, it still crashes, on this line:
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlPath, attributes]; If it really works for you, it's probably just me doing, or rather forget to do something...

Comment: Also, in your output, the attributes appear in random order (One, Three, Two).

Comment: What crash do you get on that line?

Comment: So they do come in random order. Interesting. My checking isn't what it used to be lol.

Comment: @Nilzone- can you please copy/paste the code you use to call the method? I suspect that the problem you have is passing in an NSDictionary not an NSString?

Comment: @Paulw11 http://imgur.com/bLl9nyM (when I tried to use -[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:]) The error is the same either way actually

Comment: @Nilzone- I have updated my code so it works better now. I also suggest you should move the code into a NSURLRequest category for ease of re-use.

Comment: @Gabriel I still don't get it to work. It's so close though. When I NSLog now - I get: "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id=client_id&client_secret=20140507&v=(null)". But when I call the function and pass in the attributes I have to end it with nil, otherwise I crash, why don't you have to?

Comment: @Gabriel never mind - I wasn't thinking. I way tired now. Thanks for all your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read the documentation for `-[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:]`. That method accepts a `va_list` parameter and will probably do what you want.

The reason your sample code doesn't work is because `stringWithFormat` needs a separate argument for each placeholder that appears in the format string. Your format string looks like it contains three `%@` placeholders, but you're only passing one argument, `listOfAttributes`.

Comment: I tried using -[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:] and passing in my 'list' as the argument - still crash, on the same line

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the details of the crash: what is the exact error message you see?

Answer (score 1):

The format within stringPath is specifying that there should be 3 arguments, but you are only supplying one - listOfAttributes.

listOfAttributes is one argument not 3.